# Should I use one or several repository classes?

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-room, android-livedata

I am building an Android app with Room database. I use a repostory class, as suggested in this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7). Everything works fine - I only wonder if I should use on rep.class for each DAO or if I can use on big rep.class for all my data classes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest multiple repo classes...I don't see a big problem either way, but my fear would be that the code in a single large repo.class could quickly get difficult to maintain, especially if you have a large number of DAO's.